# Nuget - Failed to download package correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

We are using NuGet server to serve our own package within the company.  Since this morning, Visual Studio's nuget plugin constantly says he cannot download package and that only on the update tab and apparently only on my machine (we are just two of us today)

The online tap well reflect all packages present in the server.

I've been reading about a race condition in the server but that concerned a previous version.

I'd like to understand what's going on and how to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had two different repositories with packages sharing the same id, same version, different content.  Removing the wrong repo from the list solved the problem.